# Font Awesome icons blinking on .load() event in JQuery

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

Using JQuery `$("#ID").load("file")` makes the font-awesome icons refresh even when `cache` is set to `false`.

```
<div id="content">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        });
        function look(str){
            $("#results").load("/iconsearch?q="+str);
        }
    </script>
    <div class="top">
        <p>Search for Icon: </p>
        <div>
            <span class="textbox-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> </span><input type="text" class="with" id="searchfield" onkeyup='look(this.value);'>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Video: https://youtu.be/TVI6I80YWz4
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TechnicalCoder/z2z5w0hf/2/

Comment: Does the `iconsearch` page include the same fonts and CSS that you have on this page?

Comment: Yes, this page is included with php over, so the page would look like a normal page with the font and everything

Comment: I have a feeling that when you load the contents from the other page, you are reloading the css and font files which is what causes the flickering of the icon. To test this, can you change your code to `$("#results").load("/iconsearch body', {q:str} );`? Does the flickering stop? Also, we'll want to use a timer to call the function after the user stops typing instead of on every keyup, but we'll get to that after we fix the flickering

Comment: The CSS are not getting reloaded cause its loaded from the root `iconwiki`

Comment: the file structure `iconwiki` > `iconsearch?q=...`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "root icon wiki". When you call load() it grabs all the content from the page, including the font and css files linked to in the head of that page. Did you try the change?

Comment: The `sender` basicly where the first document opened. root > iconwiki >etc

Comment: @DelightedD0D The CSS is not in that document, it is in the header of iconwiki

Comment: The file located at `/iconsearch`, can you navigate to that file in a browser?

Comment: `index.php?query?iconsearch&search=Pages` - This file contains all of the fonts and css, now in the body tag of this document it loads `/Pages/iconsearch.page.php` which you see here

Comment: It is called http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Can you replace your `.load()` with this `$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/iconsearch?q=" + str,
   success: function(data) {
     console.log(data); 
   },
 });`  Then copy the console.log text and put it in a pastebin or jsfiddle? I need to be able to see the actual response text.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/TechnicalCoder/z2z5w0hf/1/

Comment: When I run the files on my local server, that behaviour does not occur. The issue must be in code that you dont show, possibly in `/js/lib/dummy.js`, or the issue is dependant on some part of your setup (OS, browser, etc..)

Comment: @DelightedD0D Might be